# Change android device sound mode in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am looking for a way to change the device sound mode on a flutter application.

So if the user has set the device to be on silent mode, the app will have permissions to change it.

How can I do it with flutter ?

Is there a plugin that I can use ?

I know in React Native there is a plugin: [react-native-ringer-mode](https://github.com/ryhnnl/react-native-ringer-mode)

That dose exactly that, how can I do it in Flutter?

Comment: Using the volume package can be useful (https://pub.dev/packages/volume), however, it forgets about vibration and only works for Android... Did you find any workaround?

Comment: use the flutter_dnd package

Answer (score 0):

please use this package https://pub.dev/packages/volume 
and vibration with package https://pub.dev/packages/vibration

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:volume/volume.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  AudioManager audioManager;
  int maxVol, currentVol;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioManager = AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM;
    initPlatformState();
    updateVolumes();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    await Volume.controlVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
  }

  updateVolumes() async {
    // get Max Volume
    maxVol = await Volume.getMaxVol;
    // get Current Volume
    currentVol = await Volume.getVol;
    setState(() {});
  }

  setVol(int i) async {
    await Volume.setVol(i);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButton(
                value: audioManager,
                items: [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("In Call Volume"),
                    value: AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("System Volume"),
                    value: AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Ring Volume"),
                    value: AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Media Volume"),
                    value: AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Alarm volume"),
                    value: AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("Notifications Volume"),
                    value: AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
                  ),
                ],
                isDense: true,
                onChanged: (AudioManager aM) async {
                  print(aM.toString());
                  setState(() {
                    audioManager = aM;
                  });
                  await Volume.controlVolume(aM);
                },
              ),
              (currentVol != null || maxVol != null)
                  ? Slider(
                      value: currentVol / 1.0,
                      divisions: maxVol,
                      max: maxVol / 1.0,
                      min: 0,
                      onChanged: (double d) {
                        setVol(d.toInt());
                        updateVolumes();
                      },
                    )
                  : Container(),

              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Vol Up"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Volume.volUp();
                  updateVolumes();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Vol Down"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Volume.volDown();
                  updateVolumes();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is rather an incomplete solution, vibration control is still missing. The package that you mentioned gives you the possibility to make the phone vibrate, but not to control how incoming notifications (for instance) vibrate.